# Gráficos no ggplot2, estou querendo adicionar um loop para criar gráficos

Tags: ggplot2, r

Estou com uma duvida no ggplot, estou querendo comparar duas tabelas e criar gráficos para cada Gene no R:

Tabela 1
[image: Tabela 1]

A tabela 2 abaixo usei como referencia no índice para o loop:

[image: Tabela 2]

"gene_data" é variável para a Tabela 2, e "Saida" é variavel para Tabela 1, então queria criar um loop utilizando a tabela 2 como índice, só que o problema é que o loop está retornando só o grafico do gene "ZCWPW1", que no caso é a linha 21 da tabela 2

```
for (i in nrow(gene_data)) {
  gene_saida = subset(saida, saida$gene_symbols == gene_data$GENES[i])
  
  print(ggplot(gene_saida, aes(x=most_severe_consequence)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count")+
    labs(title = gene_data$GENES[i])+
    ylab(label = "Frequencia")+
    xlab(label = "Variantes"))
}
```

tipo eu consegir fazer manualmente todos os graficos sem o loop só que tinha que ficar mudando o gene_data$GENES[ ] dentro deste indice eu colocava o numero da linha da tabela 2 :

```
gene_saida = subset(saida, saida$gene_symbols == gene_data$GENES[1])

#FREQUENCIA DE VARIANTES LOF
ggplot(gene_saida, aes(x=most_severe_consequence)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")+
  labs(title = "Gene ZCWPW1")+
  ylab(label = "Frequencia")+
  xlab(label = "Variantes")
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Marlon, você não está fazendo o loop `for (i in nrow(gene_data))` pois não tem iteração modifique para `for (i in 1:nrow(gene_data))`

Comment: @Daniel já apontou porque seu loop não funciona. Mas o que pretende com ele? Como está, irá exibir na tela um gráfico atrás do outro.

Comment: Galera valeu pela ajuda, conseguir resolver minha duvida, a resolução está disponível.

Answer (score 1):

Galera conseguir resolver, adicionei um loop que ira percorrer todas as linhas do "gene_data" (tabela 2), e para cada linha percorrida ele ira fazer o gráfico em formato png com o nome da linha de "gene_data", por exemplo, vamos supor que ele irá percorrer a linha 1 de "gene_data", a linha 1 é o gene ABCA7 (tabela 2), então ele irá renomear o gráfico para ABCA7 que é nome contido na linha 1.

```
for (i in unique(gene_data$GENES)) {
      nome_grafico = paste(i,".png", sep = "")
      png(filename = nome_grafico, width = 15, height = 15, units = "cm", pointsize = 12, res = 150)
```

Bem, a primeira parte já foi, que era escolher o formato e renomear os gráficos, agora vamos adicionar o loop, para isso temos que fazer um subset comparando as colunas de "saida" (tabela 1) com as linhas de "gene_data", por exemplo, a linha 1 de "gene_data" é ABCA7 então o subset irá filtrar todas as linhas onde ABCA7 aparece em "saida", e por final irá gerar o grafico de ABCA7.

```
print(ggplot(subset(saida, gene_symbols == i), aes(x=most_severe_consequence)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "count")+
        labs(title = i)+
        ylab(label = "Frequencia")+
        xlab(label = "Variantes"))
      dev.off()
    }
```

Código do loop em R completo abaixo:

```
library(ggplot2)

for (i in unique(gene_data$GENES)) {
  nome_grafico = paste(i,".png", sep = "")
  png(filename = nome_grafico, width = 15, height = 15, units = "cm", pointsize = 12, res = 150)
  print(ggplot(subset(saida, gene_symbols == i), aes(x=most_severe_consequence)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count")+
    labs(title = i)+
    ylab(label = "Frequencia")+
    xlab(label = "Variantes"))
  dev.off()
}
```